# Uncaught TypeError: has no method 'storeKeyFor'

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

I am new to Sproutcore and am learning the basics. I'm stuck at the following problem:

I have a model:

```
Myapp.Space = SC.Record.extend({
    id: SC.Record.attr(Number),
    name: SC.Record.attr(String),
    creator: SC.Record.toOne('Myapp.User', {isMaster: YES, inverse: 'space'})
});

Myapp.User = SC.Record.extend({
    id: SC.Record.attr(String),
    name: SC.Record.attr(String)
});
```

And a controller:

```
Myapp.spaces_controller = SC.ArrayController.create(
 {
       allowsMultipleSelection: NO,
        selection: null,
        isEditable: YES
});
```

In my data source I am doing a remote GET call:

```
fetch: function(store, query) {
            var recordType = query.get('recordType');
            var url;
            if (recordType === Myapp.Space) {
                url = "spaces"
            }
            SC.Request.getUrl(this.baseApiUrl(store) + url).set('isJSON', YES)
                .notify(this, this._didFetch, {
                    store: store,
                    recordType: recordType
                }).send();
        },

_didFetch: function (response, params)  {
            var store = params.store,
                recordType = params.recordType;
            if (SC.$ok(response)) {
                store.loadRecords(recordType, response.get('body'));
            }
        },
```

When I call

```
Myapp.spaces_controller.set('content', Myapp.store.find(Myapp.Space));
```

(after login of the user) I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (props) {
      this.__sc_super__ = ret.prototype;
      return this._object_init(props);
    } has no method 'storeKeyFor' javascript.js?1377681200:11281
SC.Store.SC.Object.extend.loadRecord javascript.js?1377681200:11281
SC.Store.SC.Object.extend.loadRecords javascript.js?1377681200:11337
Myapp.DataSource.SC.DataSource.extend._didFetch data_source.js?1378388369:39
SC.Response.SC.Object.extend._notifyListeners javascript.js?1377681198:392
SC.Response.SC.Object.extend.notify javascript.js?1377681198:413
(anonymous function) javascript.js?1377681198:314
SC.run javascript.js?1377681203:14741
SC.Response.SC.Object.extend.receive javascript.js?1377681198:298
SC.XHRResponse.SC.Response.extend.finishRequest javascript.js?1377681198:628
SC.mixin.handle javascript.js?1377681199:4249
(anonymous function)
```

I can access the objects in the response body but the store does not get the data.

I could not find any mentioning of this error online. Can anybody help?

Comment: After posting the question I found a problem, a I had a conflicting class name. But now I ran into the next problem, I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined javascript.js?1377681200:13225
SC.RecordArray.SC.Object.extend.storeDidChangeStoreKeys javascript.js?1377681200:13225
(anonymous function) javascript.js?1377681200:10205
SC.Set.SC.mixin.forEach javascript.js?1377681203:8171
SC.Store.SC.Object.extend._notifyRecordArrays javascript.js?1377681200:10204
SC.Store.SC.Object.extend.flush`

Comment: Can you use gist.github.com to create a full-code example that fails?

Comment: Thanks for offering more help! I just resolved that issue, that was nothing Sproutcore specific, I forgot to set a parameter "query" in the callback function for the method "store.dataSourceDidFetchQuery(query)". So that's now running :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error of `Object function(props) ... has no method 'storeKeyFor'` looks to me like you are attempting to call a function on a Class rather than on an actual Instance of that class.

My first guess is that your recordType is being set as an actual class rather than a string, and that may be causing some issues. In general, I would recommend using `'MyApp.Space'` whenever dealing with record types as that will be evaluated and found at runtime. If it can't find it for some reason, it will throw a slightly nicer message.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed I had another view called Myapp.Space, so this is resolved. (Still struggling with the next error, ... :)